# how to plot training error and validation error vs number of epochs?

Tags: python, validation, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, training-data

how to plot training error and validation error vs number of epochs?

```
train_data = generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, filesPath, end=75)
validation_data=generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, filesPath, start=75)
            model.fit_generator(generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, filesPath, end=75), #end=75),#It take the first 75%
                                validation_data=generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, filesPath, start=75),#start=75), #It take the last 25%
                                #steps_per_epoch=10000, epochs=10)
                                steps_per_epoch=int((len(filesPath)-int(len(filesPath)/100*25))),#*25), 
                                validation_steps=int((len(filesPath)-int(len(filesPath)/100*75))),#*75),
                                verbose=2,
                                epochs=300, max_queue_size=2, shuffle=True, callbacks=[callback])
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking. Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: You should add more details about what you are traying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for, but you should provide more details in order to get a more suitable answer

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

hist = model.fit_generator(...)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(hist.history['loss'])
plt.plot(hist.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train','val'], loc = 'upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: thank you so much the code is worked but I get an empty figure

Comment: Is your loss changing during training? Try using `verbose = 1` in the `fit_generator` and make sure your training and validation losses are changing from epoch to epoch